# Window.location doesn't work on Phonegap/Cordova version 4 after upgrade

Tags: android, cordova, version, upgrade

I have an application based on Cordova 2.7 for Android platform.
Yesterday I had to upgrade Cordova version because of Google Play warning about vulnerabilities... 
What I did is to create a basic Cordova app throw terminal commands before upgrades.
After that I put this code into the index.js default file:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

           //navigator.app.loadUrl('http://www.google.com/');
           alert('inside');

           //console.log(navigator.app);
           //window.location = encodeURI('http://www.example.com');
           //window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/';

           window.location = 'http://www.example.com/';  <--- Not works

           //window.location = 'local_page.html';  <--- this works perfect
           //window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');

}
```

And the config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget
id="com.example.app" version="0.0.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />


<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>


<name>TPV_APP</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />

<access origin="*" />
```

Window.location doesn't work. Indeed doesn't show any posible error.
Its just doesnt work.
If window.location redirect to local pages, it works perfectly,
but for external pages it doesnt.
The alert is executed ok.

INFO: In my previous version of Cordova was working without problems.
I need to be redirected within the same webview. Not open another webview or browser.

I have been searching solutions for 2 days.
Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this? Thanks!

Comment: No, but this issue happened 1 year ago. Maybe today 13 May 2016 is solved by the Phonegap/Cordova community. What I did was to remove all Phonegap and implement a webview in Android directly.